# Appcelerator resolve uri

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, appcelerator, android-contentresolver

I'm working on a procedure to import a file within the application, in this case I am taking a google drive file.

When the user selects a file `startActivityForResult` returns a url like this:

`content: //com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc%%3D1%%3Bdoc%%3D1214`

I can not resolve this url to access the content of the file. Does anyone have experience on this?

On google I found some old module, but, I do not think solves my problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found the solution.
you need to copy the file to the applicationDataDirectory before trying to get the content.

Copying the file will automatically resolve the content uri.

```
var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
    action: Ti.Android.ACTION_GET_CONTENT,
    type: '*/*'
});

$.win.activity.startActivityForResult(intent, function(e) {

    if (e.intent) {

        var filePath = e.intent.data;
        var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(filePath);
        var copiedFile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, file.name);
        file.copy(copiedFile.nativePath); 

        if (!copiedFile.exists()) {
            // show your error message
            return;
        }

        // file content
        console.log(copiedFile.read().text);

    }
});
```